# Passing variables using excel macros in order to complete a sentence

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel macros.Please correct me if am asking anything silly.

I want to print the below CALL statement in excel sheet where SCHEMA_NAME, PROCEDURE_NAME, INPUT_DATE, EXIT_DATE are to be parameterized and I want to take these parameters from the user through a button.

```
CALL SCHEMA_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME('INPUT_DATE','EXIT_DATE',STATUS);
```

Can someone please help me to write a macro for this.

As of now I have written only the CONCATENATE statement:

```
=CONCATENATE("CALL"," ", "SCHEMA_NAME", ".", "PROCEDURE_NAME", "(", "'", "INPUT_DATE", "'", ",", "'", "EXIT_DATE", "'", ",", "STATUS", ")", ";")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You can use contants as you did and you can use variables. The values of the variables can be taken from any source. N.b.: you can omit `Concatenate` and simply use `&`. (Note the spaces before and after.) E.g.:

```
Dim s1 as String, s2 as String, sCommand as String

s1 = Inputbox ("Enter schema name")
s2 = Inputbox ("Enter procedure name")
sCommand = "Call " & s1 & "." & s2 & "('INPUT_DATE','EXIT_DATE',STATUS)"
```

Or you can take values from Excel or Word:

```
Dim s1 as String, s2 as String, sCommand as String

s1 = Cells(1, 1)       ' schema name
s2 = Cells(2, 1)       ' procedure name
sCommand = "Call " & s1 & "." & s2 & "('INPUT_DATE','EXIT_DATE',STATUS)"
```

EDIT: To generate a list of commands as you need:

```
Dim dFrom As Date, dTo As Date, d As Date
Dim iStep As Long           ' day
Dim i As Long

dFrom = "2017-01-01"
dTo =  "2017-06-30"
iStep = 10              ' days
i = 1                   ' start in column A

For d = dFrom To dTo Step iStep
     sCommand = "Call " & s1 & "." & s2 & "(" & _
           Format(d, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "," & _
           Format(d + iStep - 1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ",STATUS)"
     Cells(1, i).value = sCommand
     i = i + 1
Next
```

You can omit using sCommand and write the string directly to the cell, yet this way you can debug it easier.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the above answer. I am able to print the output on the msgbox but can you please guide me how can i print the output directly into the excel sheet on shell number A3. Thanks for your support.

Comment: `Range("A3") = sCommand`. More precisely: `Range("A3").Value = sCommand`. Or `Cells` will do the same this way: `Cells(3, 1).Value = sCommand` which is more convenient if you use it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks a  lot it is working for me now.Thank you so much

Comment: Hi All, I am able to print the CALL statements now but one more challenge is I want to print all the CALL statements with a specific range. For example: If I am entering INPUT_DATE as 1st Jan 2017 and EXIT_DATE as 30 July with a range of 10 then it should provide me the call statements like CALL SCHEMA_NAME.procedure_name ('2017-01-01','2017-01-10',STATUS); another call statement in A2 with CALL SCHEMA_NAME.procedure_name ('2017-01-10','2017-01-20',STATUS); and like this upto 30th July...I deeply appreciate the help...thanks...