# Printing the output of a macro directly on cell A1 rather than displaying on the msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to print the below output in my excel sheet rather than displaying on the msg box.

I have written the below code but I am not able to print the output of sCommand in my excel sheet.
I want to print the output on cell A1.
Thanks in advance.

```
sCommand = "Call " & s1 & "." & s2 & "(" & "'" & INPUT_DATE & "'" & "," & "'" &EXIT_DATE & "'" & "," & "STATUS " & ")" & ";"
MsgBox (sCommand)
```

Comment: you have the same issue  _in progress_ in [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822301/how-to-pass-on-the-variables-using-excel-macros-in-order-to-complete-a-sentence) . you are supposed to stick to this latter (and provide evidence of your efforts,  too)

Answer (score 1):

Same as Gadziu, but instead of using .Cells(1,1) using .Range:

```
sCommand = "Call " & s1 & "." & s2 & "(" & "'" & INPUT_DATE & "'" & "," & "'" &EXIT_DATE & "'" & "," & "STATUS " & ")" & ";"

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = sCommand
```

You should also declare which Sheet you are actually wanting to write to, as ActiveSheet will take the sheet that is currently selected/active, so this could be better defined as:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, sCommand As String

s1 = InputBox("Enter schema name")
s2 = InputBox("Enter procedure name")
Input_date = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") 'get today's date or: Input_date = InputBox("Enter Input Date")
Exit_Date = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") 'get today's date or: Exit_Date = InputBox("Enter Exit Date")
Status = InputBox("Status")

sCommand = "Call " & s1 & "." & s2 & "(" & "'" & Input_date & "'" & "," & "'" & Exit_Date & "'" & "," & Status & ")" & ";"
'concatenate your variables into a string

'ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = sCommand 'the Cells(1, 1) refer to Cells(row_number, column_number)
ws.Range("A1").Value = sCommand
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it's better way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sCommand = "Call " & s1 & "." & s2 & "(" & "'" & INPUT_DATE & "'" & "," & "'" &EXIT_DATE & "'" & "," & "STATUS " & ")" & ";"

ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = sCommand
```